# Remove all messages, when untrash a post

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I'm trying to replace default untrash message to my own with error class. `admin_notices` do everything as expected, but even if I return empty messages array in `bulk_post_updated_messages` filter, I'm still see notice, but with empty content with Edit link.

[image]

According to `wp-admin/edit.php`, messages generating based on $bulk_counts, but `bulk_post_updated_messages` filter returns $bulk_messages only and even if I change this array, nothing happened. How to access `$bulk_counts`?

```
$bulk_messages = apply_filters( 'bulk_post_updated_messages', $bulk_messages, $bulk_counts );
$bulk_counts   = array_filter( $bulk_counts );

...

// If we have a bulk message to issue:
$messages = array();
foreach ( $bulk_counts as $message => $count ) {
    if ( isset( $bulk_messages[ $post_type ][ $message ] ) ) {
        $messages[] = sprintf( $bulk_messages[ $post_type ][ $message ], number_format_i18n( $count ) );
    } elseif ( isset( $bulk_messages['post'][ $message ] ) ) {
        $messages[] = sprintf( $bulk_messages['post'][ $message ], number_format_i18n( $count ) );
    }

    if ( 'trashed' === $message && isset( $_REQUEST['ids'] ) ) {
        $ids        = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]/', '', $_REQUEST['ids'] );
        $messages[] = '<a href="' . esc_url( wp_nonce_url( "edit.php?post_type=$post_type&doaction=undo&action=untrash&ids=$ids", 'bulk-posts' ) ) . '">' . __( 'Undo' ) . '</a>';
    }

    if ( 'untrashed' === $message && isset( $_REQUEST['ids'] ) ) {
        $ids = explode( ',', $_REQUEST['ids'] );

        if ( 1 === count( $ids ) && current_user_can( 'edit_post', $ids[0] ) ) {
            $messages[] = sprintf(
                '<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a>',
                esc_url( get_edit_post_link( $ids[0] ) ),
                esc_html( get_post_type_object( get_post_type( $ids[0] ) )->labels->edit_item )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated before, bulk messages output based on `$bulk_counts` variable and can't be edited in `admin_notices` hook. This is strange, because they has their own html wrapping in `wp-admin/edit.php` without any actions and filters. So I dig deeper in WP core.

`$bulk_counts` variable generating in the `wp-admin/edit.php` in this line:

```
$bulk_counts = array(
    'updated'   => isset( $_REQUEST['updated'] ) ? absint( $_REQUEST['updated'] ) : 0,
    'locked'    => isset( $_REQUEST['locked'] ) ? absint( $_REQUEST['locked'] ) : 0,
    'deleted'   => isset( $_REQUEST['deleted'] ) ? absint( $_REQUEST['deleted'] ) : 0,
    'trashed'   => isset( $_REQUEST['trashed'] ) ? absint( $_REQUEST['trashed'] ) : 0,
    'untrashed' => isset( $_REQUEST['untrashed'] ) ? absint( $_REQUEST['untrashed'] ) : 0,
);
```

As we can see, `untrashed` key gets from the query string. If we untrash single record, this action processing in `wp-admin/post.php` in this code:

```
case 'untrash':
        check_admin_referer( 'untrash-post_' . $post_id );

        if ( ! $post ) {
            wp_die( __( 'The item you are trying to restore from the Trash no longer exists.' ) );
        }

        if ( ! $post_type_object ) {
            wp_die( __( 'Invalid post type.' ) );
        }

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'delete_post', $post_id ) ) {
            wp_die( __( 'Sorry, you are not allowed to restore this item from the Trash.' ) );
        }

        if ( ! wp_untrash_post( $post_id ) ) {
            wp_die( __( 'Error in restoring the item from Trash.' ) );
        }

        $sendback = add_query_arg(
            array(
                'untrashed' => 1,
                'ids'       => $post_id,
            ),
            $sendback
        );
        wp_redirect( $sendback );
        exit;
```

no filters and actions again, but at the end we got `wp_redirect()` function, which has a filter `wp_redirect`.

To disable messages, we must remove `untrashed=1` argument and optional `ids=***` with current post id. In my case I'm writing a flag in session and check this flag in `wp_redirect`

After redirection

```
'untrashed' => isset( $_REQUEST['untrashed'] ) ? absint( $_REQUEST['untrashed'] ) : 0;
```

part returns 0 and according to code in my initial post messages will disappear.

At this time this is the only solution which I've found. Any other solutions are welcomes.